# Xpath get the parent tag with the child tag

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, css-selectors

I am scraping a website and the website does not have the information organized in a good way like there are sometimes fields called "Transmission" and "Engine type" and sometimes those does not exist and the problem is everything is inside each **p tags**, with a **span tag** with the Title like **Transmission** and  **Engine Type**

*here you can understand it better if i show you*

Sometimes there are certain fields and sometimes there isn't

[image]

Here engine type and transmission is present in vehicle information

[image]

Here engine type and transmission is not present in vehicle information

**and there isn't any concrete way to map the fields for all pages**
Fields gets switched cause if i try to reach the engine type text with this xpath

```
'.//div[@id="result"]/div[@class="details"][2]/p[2]/text()'
```

*maximum time i get different value cause the values in the p tags gets switched around so **sometime i get transmission with this xpath and sometimes i get engine type with this xpath***

so i was thinking is their a way to get the desired fields with the span titles right beside them ?

like this

```
<div class="details">
    <p><span class="label">Chassis/VIN #:</span>017S</p>
    <p><span class="label">Displacement:</span>0 </p>
    <p><span class="label">Odometer:</span>79,111</p>
    <p><span class="label">Condition:</span><a href="#condition-rating">2-</a>
    </p>
    <p><span class="label">Body Style:</span>coupe</p>
</div>
```

Every **p** tag has a **span** tag as a title, is there a way to get the **p** tag data with the **span** tag title ?

so for example i can get **p** tag's text **engine type** with the **span** tag title text **engine type** ?

there is a way to get a item by text in xpath like this

```
"//*[contains(text(), 'The Text Associated With The Element')]/text()"
```

is there a way to implement something like this here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of Title/Value pairs with:

```
//div[@class="details"]/p//text()
```

*Output:*

```
Chassis/VIN #: 
017S
Displacement: 
0 
Odometer: 
79,111
Condition: 
2-  
Body Style: 
coupe
```

If you want to get specific value by title, e.g. by `"Odometer:"`:

```
//div[@class="details"]/p[span="Odometer:"]/text()
```

*Output:*

```
79,111
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Andersson